# How to install Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04.2 to Lenovo L340?

Tags: software-installation

I would like to make my computer dual boot. I saw from Lenovo Setup utility that boot mode is UEFI so I need to make my bootable USB on GPT style. So how can I burn Windows 10 bootable usb on Ubuntu 20.04 with GPT style?

Comment: So Ubuntu is already installed?

Comment: Currently the computer has no OS but I have another computer with Ubuntu and an USB stick that I would like to use in installation.

Comment: Good news then! Installing windows *after* Ubuntu can be a real challenge. Try this: create the usb with a GPT partition table and NTFS format. Then mount the windows ISO and copy the contents to the usb. Boot the computer and select the proper UEFI entry. Before that, you can partition your disk the way you like it.

Comment: So how do I create the usb with a GPT partition table an NTFS format? I tried to look such an option from the program Disks.

Comment: Let me try this first, I think I've done it like this sometime ago, but I may be wrong.